# CSS, same LI rule for two IDs

Tags: html, css

I'm a CSS noob, this is my very simple code:

This works:

```
#sortingAlbums,#sortingPictures { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 80%; }
```

But if I try to do this:

```
 #sortingAlbums,sortingPictures li   { margin: 10px; padding: 0px;  font-size: 17px; 
height: 305px; width:225px; float: left; }
```

it does not work, so I am kind of stuck duplicating like so:

```
     #sortingAlbums li   { margin: 10px; padding: 0px;  font-size: 17px; 
height: 305px; width:225px; float: left; }
     #sortingPictures li { margin: 10px; padding: 0px;  font-size: 17px; 
height: 305px; width:225px; float: left; }
```

I was wondering if there is an easier way to get #sortingAlbums and $sortingPicture 's LIs to behave identical without duplicating them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I make this CSS simpler to avoid repeating the parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894789/can-i-make-this-css-simpler-to-avoid-repeating-the-parent-selector)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052635/is-there-a-way-to-shorten-css-selectors/25052868?s=5|1.0134#25052868.

Comment: Please include HTML for context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each comma-separated value needs to be a complete, valid selector. So, this is what you're after:

```
#sortingAlbums li, 
#sortingPictures li 
{ 
    margin: 10px; padding: 0px;  font-size: 17px; 
    height: 305px; width:225px; float: left; 
}
```